# Scala how to use reduceBykey when I have two keys

Tags: scala, mapreduce

Data format of one row：

```
id: 123456  
Topiclist: ABCDE:1_8;5_10#BCDEF:1_3;7_11
```

One id can have many rows:

```
id: 123456 
Topiclist:ABCDE:1_1;7_2;#BCDEF:1_2;7_11#
```

Target: `(123456, (ABCDE,9,2),(BCDEF,5,2))`

Records in topic list are split by `#`, so `ABCDE:1_8;5_10` is one record.

A record is in the format `<topicid>:<topictype>_<topicvalue>`

E.g for `ABCDE:1_8` has

topicid = ABCDE

topictype = 1

topicvalue = 8

Target: sum the total value of `TopicType1` , and count frequency of `TopicType1`
so should be `(id, (topicid, value,frequency))`, eg: `(123456, (ABCDE,9,2),(BCDEF,5,2))`

Comment: Do you have any code examples of what you have done so far?

Comment: what do you mean by one row ? is that one line or three lines? and reduceBykey is an api for spark.

Comment: I'm more curious at where the topic types come into it.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your data are "123456!ABCDE:1_8;5_10#BCDEF:1_3;7_11" and "123456!ABCDE:1_1;7_2#BCDEF:1_2;7_11", so we use "!" to get your userID "123456"

```
rdd.map{f=>
          val userID = f.split("!")(0)
          val items = f.split("!")(1).split("#")
          var result = List[Array[String]]()
          for (item <- items){
            val topicID = item.split(":")(0)
            for (topicTypeValue <- item.split(":")(1).split(";") ){
              println(topicTypeValue);
              if (topicTypeValue.split("_")(0)=="1"){result = result:+Array(topicID,topicTypeValue.split("_")(1),"1") }
            }
          }
          (userID,result)
          }
    .flatMapValues(x=>x).filter(f=>f._2.length==3)
    .map{f=>( (f._1,f._2(0)),(f._2(1).toInt,f._2(2).toInt) )}
    .reduceByKey{case(x,y)=> (x._1+y._1,x._2+y._2) }
    .map(f=>(f._1._1,(f._1._2,f._2._1,f._2._2)))   // (userID, (TopicID,valueSum,frequences) )
```

The output is ("12345",("ABCDE",9,2)), ("12345",("BCDEF",5,2))  a little different from your output, you can group this result if you really need ("12345",("ABCDE",9,2), ("BCDEF",5,2) )

Comment: Thank a lot! Very useful

Comment: Error: Unregistering ApplicationMaster with FAILED (diag message: User class threw exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type scala.Iterable[(String, Double, Double)] is not supported)